# Force redirect to HTTPS except one directory with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

I am trying redirect all website http to https except one directory "test_folder".

My original code is here ..
This code make all website to HTTPS.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But I want only this directory/folder "test_folder" to keep HTTP not HTTPS

I tried this code below, but it won't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !test_folder [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Would you please tell me what is wrong or how can I fix this issue.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: Yes, I did clear my browser cache and close my browser , but still same issue.